# How do i add documents to elasticsearch using NEST Bulk Api

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am new in Elasticsearch. 
I need to insert documents using bulk option using NEST api.

I have to index 5000 documents from a table. Below is the code that i use for bulk indexing.

```cs
public ActionResult CreateBulk()
        {            

            var descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();          

            foreach (var test in db.Attendance.Take(5000).ToList())
            {
                descriptor.Index<Attendance>(op => op.Document(new Attendance
                {
                    AttendanceId = test.AttendanceId,
                    AttendanceDate = test.AttendanceDate,
                    Estate = test.Estate,
                    Division = test.Division,
                    FieldNo = test.FieldNo,
                    Employee = test.Employee,
                    Activity = test.Activity,
                    Quantity = test.Quantity
                }));                
            }
            var bulkresult = ElasticClient.Bulk(descriptor);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

But when i run the code, i am getting the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Nest
  StackTrace:
       at Nest.NestSerializer.SerializeBulkDescriptor(IBulkRequest bulkRequest) in c:\Users\gmarz\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ExposedInternals\NestSerializer.cs:line 166
       at Nest.ElasticClient.<Bulk>b__1b6(ElasticsearchPathInfo`1 p, BulkDescriptor d) in c:\Users\gmarz\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Bulk.cs:line 31
       at Nest.ElasticClient.Dispatch[D,Q,R](D descriptor, Func`3 dispatch) in c:\Users\gmarz\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ElasticClient.cs:line 82
       at Nest.ElasticClient.Dispatch[D,Q,R](Func`2 selector, Func`3 dispatch) in c:\Users\gmarz\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ElasticClient.cs:line 70
       at Nest.ElasticClient.Bulk(Func`2 bulkSelector) in c:\Users\gmarz\code\elasticsearch-net\src\Nest\ElasticClient-Bulk.cs:line 27
       at AttendancePOC.Controllers.AttendanceController.CreateBulk() in D:\GIT Source\ElasticSearch\AttendancePOC\AttendancePOC\Controllers\AttendanceController.cs:line 114
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
  InnerException:
```

Please help me.. Is anything wrong in my code?.

Comment: Mind posting your ConnectionSettings?  Are you doing any sort of custom serialization?  Also, what version of ES and NEST are you using?

Comment: @Greg i am using ES version 1.3.2 and NEST veraion 1.1.1.

Comment: Greg Marzouka my connection string is :
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="server=10.20.3.200\SQLExpress;User id=test;database=AttendancePOC;PASSWORD=test@123;pooling=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: I didn't mean your connection string to SQL, I meant the ConnectionSettings class you're passing to your ElasticClient instance.  Are you changing any of the serialization settings?

Comment: @Greg Marzouka...No i didn't change any settings. private static ElasticClient ElasticClient
        {
            get
            {
                var setting = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));                
                return new ElasticClient(setting);
            }
        }

Comment: Getting the same error. Found a fix for this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same exact problem.
I forgot about setting up the index name for this query.
I had set up a configuration which was setting up a default index during creation of new ElasticClient, but the configuration changed and my index was null.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and the solution was to include the `defaultIndex` property in `ConnectionSettings` as stated [here](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/connecting.html) eg:

```cs
var node = new Uri("http://something:9200");
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(node, "someDefaultIndexValue");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this :

```cs
        var node = new Uri(elasticSearchURI);
        var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(new[] { node });
        var config = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool)
                                .SniffOnConnectionFault(false)
                                .SniffOnStartup(false)
                                .SetTimeout(600000)
                                .DisablePing();
        var EsClient = new ElasticClient(config);
```

Then i create the index and after that i use something like this:

```cs
        List<Categories> categList = new List<Categories>();

        if (categoriesData != null)
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(categoriesData, element =>
            {
                Categories inf = new Categories();

                inf.Code = element.Code;
                inf.Level = element.Level;

                lock(categList)
                {
                    categList.Add(inf);
                }

            });

            EsClient.IndexMany<Categories>(categList,"index_name","type_name")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add default index like this
 connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool).DefaultIndex("indexname")